# Calculate a linear Transformation $T: P_2(\Bbb R) \to \Bbb R^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Let $\beta =$ {$x^2, 1, x$} be an ordered basis for $P_2 (\Bbb{R})$ and $\gamma = \begin{bmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\1 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\0 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0 \end{pmatrix} \end{bmatrix} $ be an ordered basis for $\Bbb R^3$. Suppose the matrix for a linear transformation $T: P_2(\Bbb R) \to \Bbb R^3$ is given  by $[T]_\beta^\gamma$ is $\begin{pmatrix} 2&0&1\\1&-1&0\\1&1&1 \end{pmatrix}$. Calculate $T(4+x+3x^2)$

My teacher posted this question on the study guide for our test next week but I have never on worked a problem like this and she wasn't much help when I asked her for tips. Is it as simple as I think (Multiplying $\begin{pmatrix}3\\4\\1 \end{pmatrix}$ by the transformation matrix) or am I going about it completely wrong?

Comment: For example, $T(x^2)$ is $2\cdot (0,0,1) + (0,1,1) + (1,0,0)$. In other words, $(2,1,1)$ is the coordinate vector of $T(x^2)$ w.r.t. the given basis of $\mathbb R^3$.

Comment: There was a typo in my $\gamma$ basis, please note. My brain is very tired- how would this help me calculate the polynomial in full

Comment: T(4+x+3x²) = 4T(1) + T(x) + 3T(x²).

Comment: I wish you had written an answer and not a comment so I could upvote it lol. Thank you

Comment: I do have one more question though. Is it wrong to assume that the 3x3 matrix is arranged like the $\beta$ basis? Ie. is the second column the transformation for T(1)? Or is it arranged like $\gamma$ and the second column is T(x)? I think it's arranged like $\gamma$ but I'm doubting myself.

Comment: The columns correspond to $\beta$ and the entries in each column are the coefficients w.r.t. $\gamma$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short your simple idea is correct.

It is true that for a basis $\beta$ of vector space $V$ (finite dimensional), and basis $C$ of finite dimensional vector space $W$, then if $T: V\to W$ is a linear transformation; we have for any vector $v \in V$:
$$[T]_{\beta \to C}[v]_{\beta}=[T(v)]_C$$

So your method will produce the co-ordinate vector of your transformed vector, and as your target is $\mathbb{R^3}$ you'd normally just leave that as your answer. In this case your basis is ordered in a non-standard way so you'd have to swap the first and last co-ordinate to get your vector in  $\mathbb{R}^3$. In this specific example

$$\begin{bmatrix}2 & 0 & 1\\1 & -1 &0 \\ 1 & 1 & 1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}3\\4\\ 1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}7\\-1\\ 8\end{bmatrix}$$ Which is the coordinate vector of the transformed vector in terms of $\gamma$. Thus your final vector is given by:
$$ 7\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\1\end{pmatrix}-1\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}+8\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}8\\-1\\7\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Why would I swap the first and last coordinates? Wouldn't it be the second and last? And would I swap them before or after multiplication?

Comment: I've edited the post to show you your example explicitly